# React Native: How to select the next TextInput after pressing the "next" keyboard button?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-textinput

I defined two TextInput fields as follows:

```
<TextInput 
   style = {styles.titleInput}
   returnKeyType = {"next"}
   autoFocus = {true}
   placeholder = "Title" />
<TextInput
   style = {styles.descriptionInput}          
   multiline = {true}
   maxLength = {200}
   placeholder = "Description" />
```

But after pressing the "next" button on my keyboard, my react-native app isn't jumping to the second TextInput field. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Mitch's answer (currently the 3rd one down) works for me on v0.42.

Comment: For people on React  `v16.8.0` or above I'd recommend the answer provided by  @Eli Johnson towards the bottom. React has deprecated many uses of  `ref` provided in solutions below.

Answer (score 466, accepted):

Set the second `TextInput` focus, when the previous `TextInput`'s `onSubmitEditing` is triggered.

Try this

1. Adding a Ref to **second TextInput**
   `ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}`
2. Bind focus function to **first TextInput**'s onSubmitEditing event.
   `onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}`
3. Remember to set blurOnSubmit to false, to prevent keyboard flickering.
   `blurOnSubmit={false}`

> When all done, it should looks like this.

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="FirstTextInput"
    returnKeyType="next"
    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
/>

<TextInput
    ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
    placeholder="secondTextInput"
/>
```

Comment: Worth to mention, that `onSubmitEditing` callback is called after `blur` event. So the keyboard may go crazy if focused on next element immediately. So it might be helpful to set `blurOnSubmit={false}` to all elements in form but leave at `true` on last element, to allow **Done** button to blur the last input.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as of v0.36. There is no method "focus" on the component. How should we do this now?

Comment: @Mitch could you find an answer for this?

Comment: @tarkanlar Yes. My solution feels like a hack, but I *think* it is the best solution available right now. See my answer below.

Comment: @Mitch works fine on 0.40.0. Might have been a bug in the version you were running.

Comment: Use funcution setFocus() instead focus()

Comment: `this.refs.SecondInput.focus();`  or `this.refs.SecondInput.setFocus();`  do not work . Using `react-native 0.45.1`

Comment: @jasan it worked for me. Make sure to use `onEndEditing` instead of `onSubmitEditing`.

Comment: I have just one input and I need to focus itself after each submit but I'm still trying to achieve it. Some idea? I'm using the example in https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html for RN 0.44. `onEndEditing` doesn't work to me because I have other buttons in the view that need to keep working.

Comment: @jasan @Olivia I'm using `onSubmitEditing` on `react-native 0.45.1` just fine.

Comment: How can we focus react-native Picker?

Comment: I am using react-native : 0.48.4 this sample code is not working @boredgames

Comment: Using RN 0.49, adding `blurOnSubmit={false}` to prevent keyboard flickering caused this to stop working, any one that knows what's going on?

Comment: Tried this in RN 0.47 aaaaand... IT WORKS!

Comment: For anyone who couldn't manage to make `focus` work, make sure you don't use a wrapper for `TextInput` component. If you have a say `CustomTextInput` component that wraps `TextInput`, you need to implement `TextInput` blur and focus methods for that component so it will work as expected.

Comment: Works with 0.53

Comment: how can we add next button in keyboard with keyboardType=phone-pad''??

Comment: @RishabhBhardwaj i believe phone pad does not have a next button

Comment: Not working on RN 0.59.3 (there isn't a method named `focus()` on `TextInput` (no, I'm not using a wrapper)

Comment: @CihadTurhan I recommend spreading props and passing that down to `CustomTextInput` so that the TextInput props can be used. Ex: `<TextInput customProp="customValue" {...rest} />`

Comment: Is there any cleaner way with formik? I'm building a form with 15 inputs I don't want to have a component with 15 useRef hooks my component is going to be really messy

Answer (score 132):

Thought I would share my solution using a function component... '*this*' not needed!

> React 16.12.0 and React Native 0.61.5

Here is an example of my component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
...


const MyFormComponent = () => {

  const ref_input2 = useRef();
  const ref_input3 = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Input1"
        autoFocus={true}
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={() => ref_input2.current.focus()}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Input2"
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={() => ref_input3.current.focus()}
        ref={ref_input2}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Input3"
        ref={ref_input3}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: not working. undefined is not object evaluating _this2.ref_input2.current,please help

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of your code?

Comment: For those who like keeping up with the latest react updates, this is THE ANSWER.

Comment: Nice solution. I recommend including `blurOnSubmit={false}` on the first two inputs to prevent keyboard flicker

Comment: ref_input2.current.focus() didnt work, the solution I used is ref_input2.current._root.focus()

Comment: Hey, is it possible to have an object instead of a single ref for every field?

Comment: For those that are using a wrapper component for Text Input, I found that I needed to pass down Ref using [React.forwardRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) and then pass ref as prop to Text Input

Comment: @EliJohnson I am trying to implement your solution here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64469245/change-focus-automatically-to-next-input-with-react-native but am having issues, any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @404notBrighton Your solution worked. I am using expo sdk 41 that uses RN 0.63

Comment: @grant, I needed that option also :)

Comment: Anybody know how to do this with TypeScript? React complains when you assign the ref defined by `useRef` to the `ref` prop, amazingly... EDIT: just need to add a union type with `null`, duh. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313784/react-native-text-input-focus-with-useref-using-typescript

Comment: Its also better to use null checks before accessing it. Like
ref_input2?.current?.focus();

here it won't effect, but if you access ref of ScrollView it will crash.

Comment: for anyone using typescript and getting Object is possibly 'null'. change these two lines: `const ref_input2 = useRef<TextInput | null>(null);` and `onSubmitEditing={() => ref_input2.current?.focus()}`

Answer (score 76):

You can do this **without using refs**. This approach is preferred, since refs can lead to **fragile code**. The [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) advise finding other solutions where possible:

> If you have not programmed several apps with React, your first
>   inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things
>   happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more
>   critically about where state should be owned in the component
>   hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to "own" that
>   state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. Placing the state there
>   often eliminates any desire to use refs to "make things happen" –
>   instead, the data flow will usually accomplish your goal.

Instead, we'll use a state variable to focus the second input field.

1. Add a state variable that we'll pass as a prop to the `DescriptionInput`:

   ```
   initialState() {
     return {
       focusDescriptionInput: false,
     };
   }
   ```
2. Define a handler method that will set this state variable to true:

   ```
   handleTitleInputSubmit() {
     this.setState(focusDescriptionInput: true);
   }
   ```
3. Upon submitting / hitting enter / next on the `TitleInput`, we'll call `handleTitleInputSubmit`. This will set `focusDescriptionInput` to true.

   ```
   <TextInput 
      style = {styles.titleInput}
      returnKeyType = {"next"}
      autoFocus = {true}
      placeholder = "Title" 
      onSubmitEditing={this.handleTitleInputSubmit}
   />
   ```
4. `DescriptionInput`'s `focus` prop is set to our `focusDescriptionInput` state variable. So, when `focusDescriptionInput` changes (in step 3), `DescriptionInput` will re-render with `focus={true}`.

   ```
   <TextInput
      style = {styles.descriptionInput}          
      multiline = {true}
      maxLength = {200}
      placeholder = "Description" 
      focus={this.state.focusDescriptionInput}
   />
   ```

This is a nice way to avoid using refs, since refs can lead to more fragile code :)

EDIT: h/t to @LaneRettig for pointing out that you'll need to wrap the React Native TextInput with some added props & methods to get it to respond to `focus`:

```
    // Props:
    static propTypes = { 
        focus: PropTypes.bool,
    } 

    static defaultProps = { 
        focus: false,
    } 

    // Methods:
    focus() {
        this._component.focus(); 
    } 

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const {focus} = nextProps; 

        focus && this.focus(); 
    }
```

Comment: I'm using RN 0.19 and this approach isn't working for me. Setting focus={} on a TextInput doesn't seem to have any effect when the prop's value changes.

Comment: @LaneRettig can you make sure that your component is re-rendering upon changes to `this.state.focusDescriptionInput`?

You can just log it in the render() method (`console.log(this.state.focusDescriptionInput);`) and see if it prints out upon calling `handleTitleInputSubmit()`.

Also, make sure that the value being set to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: I tried this again. Confirmed that the variables are being set properly, and that the view is being re-rendered. Setting focus={this.state.foo} on a TextInput does not work in the current version of RN, as far as I can tell!

Comment: @LaneRettig You're totally right -- thanks for pointing that out. We wrap RN TextInput with some added props and methods -- please see the bottom of the answer w/ those additions and let me know if you have any further issues!

Comment: Cool. You should submit this as a PR to RN. I'm surprised this isn't already supported out of the box.

Comment: what if you click next on keyboard, and then click directly on first input? focus goes back to second which is bad experience with that solution

Comment: This is a much messier solution than the first solution. The best solution would be a memo-bind type solution: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/659 and specifically https://github.com/supnate/memobind

Comment: @chapinkapa Can you give an example of how this would work with the memobind solution?

Comment: How is `this._component` initialized?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Could you please post the complete code?

Comment: I don't love this solution, in particular because it doesn't scale well for even slightly longer forms of 5-6 elements, where you'd need a focus boolean in state for each element & manage them all accordingly.

Comment: Interestingly, the docs also state:
"There are a few good use cases for refs: Managing focus, text selection, or media playback..." So in this case, using refs for focusing text input would be a valid use of the tool.

Comment: doest text input have prop 'focus'? I just check the doc, it aint

Comment: This solution still may be useful for specific use-cases. I'll give it a try since I do need to use the ref for my testing framework (https://github.com/pixielabs/cavy) and I can't use the refs because of it

Comment: Is this still working? This is not documented: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

Comment: But you have used a ref here, and focus is not really a state that belongs to an individual component, it's a state that applies to the enitire screen. So passing a prop to indicate whether it is focused seems odd. when using refs, whichever component's focus method was called last would be the one in focus.

Answer (score 28):

As of React Native 0.36, calling `focus()` (as suggested in several other answers) on a text input node isn't supported any more. Instead, you can use the `TextInputState` module from React Native. I created the following helper module to make this easier:

```
// TextInputManager
//
// Provides helper functions for managing the focus state of text
// inputs. This is a hack! You are supposed to be able to call
// "focus()" directly on TextInput nodes, but that doesn't seem
// to be working as of ReactNative 0.36
//
import { findNodeHandle } from 'react-native'
import TextInputState from 'react-native/lib/TextInputState'


export function focusTextInput(node) {
  try {
    TextInputState.focusTextInput(findNodeHandle(node))
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Couldn't focus text input: ", e.message)
  }
}
```

You can, then, call the `focusTextInput` function on any "ref" of a `TextInput`. For example:

```
...
<TextInput onSubmit={() => focusTextInput(this.refs.inputB)} />
<TextInput ref="inputB" />
...
```

Comment: I couldn't make this work maybe because I use redux-form

Comment: Works awesome but if anyone uses redux-form should do something like this.
`<Field ... onSubmitEditing={() => focusTextInput(this._password)}
                  />`
and ref should be like this `<Field ...
                    withRef
                    refName={e => this._password = e}/>`

Comment: I had to use 'onSubmitEditing' to make this work but great solution none the less.

Comment: Works great in 0.42.

Comment: @tarkanlar can you share code snippet for the solution? I can't seem to focus when using redux-form Field, using just TextInput works, fine

Comment: Works with 0.46

Comment: Works in 0.46 with a small change:
`import * as TextInputState from 'react-native/lib/TextInputState'`

Comment: `calling focus() on a text input node isn't supported any more` => bold claim, source? Calling `focus()` works fine with v0.49.5 + `TextInputState` is not documented while `focus()` and `blur()` are mentioned: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/textinput.html

Comment: @tanguy_k My source is the RN source code as of v0.36 . It seems that this has been addressed in later versions of RN.

Comment: I can confirm that `focus()` works with RN 0.57, I got it to work very similarly to this answer:

`onSubmitEditing={() => (this.refs.password as TextInput).focus()}`

Answer (score 25):

I created a small library that does this, no code change needed other than replacing your wrapping view and import of TextInput:

```
import { Form, TextInput } from 'react-native-autofocus'

export default () => (
  <Form>
    <TextInput placeholder="test" />
    <TextInput placeholder="test 2" />
  </Form>
)
```

https://github.com/zackify/react-native-autofocus

Explained in detail here: https://zach.codes/autofocus-inputs-in-react-native/

Comment: Excellent pattern for achieving this result. Should be top answer from ease of use stand point. Looks like I can easily edit my custom FormInput (TextInput extensions) to still work with your Form inputs. Mind if I include it to your answer if for further example?

Comment: Sure! I know... I posted this on the other popular post about this but got in trouble for duplicates. Just trying to help because I know how annoying this problem is!!

Comment: This is great if you have a bunch of TextInputs right after each other but if you want to add styling between them it breaks down. Thanks for the contribution though.

Comment: Feel free to adjust the code. I’m sure you could make a way that would skip over elements that are not text inputs. Shouldn’t be too hard to do.

Comment: This does not build for production RN@0.47.2

Comment: Feel free to make a pr, I'll check it out when i get some free time!

Comment: Excellent Work!

Comment: This breaks in production.

Answer (score 16):

Combining @Eli Johnson's solution for functional components with @Rodrigo Tessarollo's solution for a CustomTextInput:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { CustomTextInput } from 'path/to/CustomTextInput';
...


export const MyFormComponent = () => {

  const ref_to_input2 = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <CustomTextInput
        placeholder="Input 1"
        autoFocus={true}
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={() => ref_to_input2.current.focus()}
      />
      <CustomTextInput
        placeholder="Input 2"
        returnKeyType="done"
        refInner={ref_to_input2}
        onSubmitEditing={/* Do something! */}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

and in your CustomTextInput component:

```
import { TextInput } from "react-native";
export const CustomTextInput = (props) => {
  <TextInput
        ref={props.refInner}
        {...props}
  />
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to have a single Ref for all inputs? Your solution worked, but in big forms it is quite verbose to have a single ref for each input.

Answer (score 15):

Using react-native 0.45.1 I also encountered problems trying to set focus on a password TextInput after pressing return key on a username TextInput.

After having tried most of the top rated solutions here on SO I found a solution on github that fulfilled my needs:
https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/44#issuecomment-290724642

To sum it up:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput as RNTextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class TextInput extends Component {
    render() {
        const { props } = this;

        return (
            <RNTextInput
                {...props}
                ref={(input) => props.inputRef && props.inputRef(input)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import TextInput from "../../components/TextInput";

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.passTextInput = null
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{flex:1}}
                    placeholder="Username"
                    onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
                        this.passTextInput.focus()
                    }}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={{flex:1}}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    inputRef={(input) => {
                        this.passTextInput = input
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You save my life : )

Comment: You've merely renamed `ref` to `inputRef`...  You could drop your entire custom component and your second code block will work as-is as long as you revert back to using `ref`

Answer (score 12):

For me on RN 0.50.3 it's possible with this way:

```
<TextInput 
  autoFocus={true} 
  onSubmitEditing={() => {this.PasswordInputRef._root.focus()}} 
/>

<TextInput ref={input => {this.PasswordInputRef = input}} />
```

You must see this.PasswordInputRef.**_root**.focus()

Comment: This is 'native-base' specific

Answer (score 9):

My scenario is **< CustomBoladonesTextInput />** wrapping a RN **< TextInput />**.

I solved this issue as follow:

My form looks like:

```
  <CustomBoladonesTextInput 
      onSubmitEditing={() => this.customInput2.refs.innerTextInput2.focus()}
      returnKeyType="next"
      ... />

  <CustomBoladonesTextInput 
       ref={ref => this.customInput2 = ref}
       refInner="innerTextInput2"
       ... />
```

On CustomBoladonesTextInput's component definition, I pass the refField to the inner  ref prop like this:

```
   export default class CustomBoladonesTextInput extends React.Component {
      render() {        
         return (< TextInput ref={this.props.refInner} ... />);     
      } 
   }
```

And voila. Everything get back works again. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to be using [`tcomb-form-native`](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/) as I am, you can do this, too. Here's the trick: instead of setting the props of the `TextInput` directly, you do it via `options`. You can refer to the fields of the form as:

```
this.refs.form.getComponent('password').refs.input.focus()
```

So the final product looks something like this:

```
var t = require('tcomb-form-native');
var Form = t.form.Form;

var MyForm = t.struct({
  field1:     t.String,
  field2:     t.String,
});

var MyComponent = React.createClass({

  _getFormOptions () {
    return {
      fields: {
        field1: {
          returnKeyType: 'next',
          onSubmitEditing: () => {this.refs.form.getComponent('field2').refs.input.focus()},
        },
      },
    };
  },

  render () {

    var formOptions = this._getFormOptions();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Form ref="form" type={MyForm} options={formOptions}/>
      </View>
    );
  },
});
```

(Credit to remcoanker for posting the idea here: https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/issues/96)

Comment: how do I call function onSubmitEditing ? for ex: I want to call login() function when user press last textinput's returnkeytype 'done'.

Answer (score 8):

This is the way I achieved it. And the example below has used the React.createRef() API introduced in React 16.3.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.secondTextInputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "FirstTextInput"
                returnKeyType="next"
                onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInputRef.current.focus(); }}
            />
            <TextInput
                ref={this.secondTextInputRef}
                placeholder = "secondTextInput"
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: what is the purpose of .current?

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution on React Native's GitHub issues.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2149#issuecomment-129262565

You need to use the ref prop for the TextInput component.
Then you need a create a function that gets called on onSubmitEditing prop that moves the focus on the second TextInput ref.

```
var InputScreen = React.createClass({
    _focusNextField(nextField) {
        this.refs[nextField].focus()
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    ref='1'
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Normal'
                    returnKeyType='next'
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusNextField('2')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    ref='2'
                    style={styles.input}
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                    placeholder='Email Address'
                    returnKeyType='next'
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusNextField('3')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    ref='3'
                    style={styles.input}
                    keyboardType='url'
                    placeholder='URL'
                    returnKeyType='next'
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusNextField('4')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    ref='4'
                    style={styles.input}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    placeholder='Numeric'
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusNextField('5')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    ref='5'
                    style={styles.input}
                    keyboardType='numbers-and-punctuation'
                    placeholder='Numbers & Punctuation'
                    returnKeyType='done'
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include the relative information from the link in your answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that string refs may become deprecated so this solution may not work in the future: "...Although string refs are not deprecated, they are considered legacy, and will likely be deprecated at some point in the future. Callback refs are preferred." -- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as of v0.36. There is no method "focus" on the component. How should we do this now? Can you update the answer?

Comment: @Mitch not sure if this is back on 0.39.2 but this works fine now.

Answer (score 5):

```
<TextInput placeholder="Nombre"
    ref="1"
    editable={true}
    returnKeyType="next"
    underlineColorAndroid={'#4DB6AC'}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    value={this.state.First_Name}
    onChangeText={First_Name => this.setState({ First_Name })}
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.focusNextField('2')}
    placeholderTextColor="#797a7a" style={{ marginBottom: 10, color: '#808080', fontSize: 15, width: '100%', }} />

<TextInput placeholder="Apellido"
    ref="2"
    editable={true}
    returnKeyType="next"
    underlineColorAndroid={'#4DB6AC'}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    value={this.state.Last_Name}
    onChangeText={Last_Name => this.setState({ Last_Name })}
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.focusNextField('3')}
    placeholderTextColor="#797a7a" style={{ marginBottom: 10, color: '#808080', fontSize: 15, width: '100%', }} />
```

and add method

```
focusNextField(nextField) {
    this.refs[nextField].focus();
}
```

Comment: Old answer but does anyone know if it's possible to access all refs like in this answer in a functional (stateless) component?

Answer (score 4):

Using callback refs instead of the [legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468913/why-ref-string-is-legacy) string refs:

```
<TextInput
    style = {styles.titleInput}
    returnKeyType = {"next"}
    autoFocus = {true}
    placeholder = "Title"
    onSubmitEditing={() => {this.nextInput.focus()}}
/>
<TextInput
    style = {styles.descriptionInput}  
    multiline = {true}
    maxLength = {200}
    placeholder = "Description"
    ref={nextInput => this.nextInput = nextInput}
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work as the focus-method has been removed from TextInput.

Answer (score 2):

For the accepted solution to work if your `TextInput` is inside another component, you'll need to "pop" the reference from `ref` to the parent container.

```
// MyComponent
render() {
    <View>
        <TextInput ref={(r) => this.props.onRef(r)} { ...this.props }/>
    </View>
}

// MyView
render() {
    <MyComponent onSubmitEditing={(evt) => this.myField2.focus()}/>
    <MyComponent onRef={(r) => this.myField2 = r}/>
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eldelshell, I would like to achieve the same thing, but could not sort out your sample, would you mind show us a hint?

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. I follow this and it works.

Comment: are these both in the same file?

Answer (score 2):

in your component:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.focusNextField = this
            .focusNextField
            .bind(this);
        // to store our input refs
        this.inputs = {};
    }
    focusNextField(id) {
        console.log("focus next input: " + id);
        this
            .inputs[id]
            ._root
            .focus();
    }
```

Note: I used `._root` because it is a ref to TextInput in [NativeBase'Library' Input](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Input.js)

and in your text inputs like this

```
<TextInput
         onSubmitEditing={() => {
                          this.focusNextField('two');
                          }}
         returnKeyType="next"
         blurOnSubmit={false}/>


<TextInput      
         ref={input => {
              this.inputs['two'] = input;
                        }}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextInput 
    keyboardType="email-address"
    placeholder="Email"
    returnKeyType="next"
    ref="email"
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.focusTextInput(this.refs.password)}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
 />
<TextInput
    ref="password"
    placeholder="Password" 
    secureTextEntry={true} />
```

And add method for `onSubmitEditing={() => this.focusTextInput(this.refs.password)}` as below:

```
private focusTextInput(node: any) {
    node.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how achieved this for reactjs phone code inputs

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function Header(props) {

  const [state , setState] = useState({
        phone_number:"",
        code_one:'',
        code_two:'',
        code_three:'',
        code_four:'',
        submitted:false,

  })

   const codeOneInput = useRef(null);
   const codeTwoInput = useRef(null);
   const codeThreeInput = useRef(null);
   const codeFourInput = useRef(null);

   const handleCodeChange = (e) => {
        const {id , value} = e.target
        if(value.length < 2){
            setState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                [id] : value
            }))
            if(id=='code_one' && value.length >0){
                codeTwoInput.current.focus();
            }
            if(id=='code_two'  && value.length >0){
                codeThreeInput.current.focus();
            }
            if(id=='code_three'  && value.length >0){
                codeFourInput.current.focus();
            }
        }
    }

    const sendCodeToServer = () => {

         setState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                submitted : true,
          }))
  let codeEnteredByUser = state.code_one + state.code_two + state.code_three + state.code_four

        axios.post(API_BASE_URL, {code:codeEnteredByUser})
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })

   }

   return(
        <>

           <div className="are">
                 <div className="POP-INN-INPUT">
                                        <input type="text" id="code_one" ref={codeOneInput}    value={state.code_one}  onChange={handleCodeChange} autoFocus/>
                                        <input type="text" id="code_two"  ref={codeTwoInput}  value={state.code_two} onChange={handleCodeChange}/>
                                        <input type="text" id="code_three"  ref={codeThreeInput} value={state.code_three}  onChange={handleCodeChange}/>
                                        <input type="text" id="code_four" ref={codeFourInput}  value={state.code_four}  onChange={handleCodeChange}/>
                                    </div>

            <button disabled={state.submitted} onClick={sendCodeToServer}>
   
    </div>

       </>
    )
}
export default
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to capture **tabs** in a `TextInput`. It's hacky, but better than [nothing](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/641).

Define an `onChangeText` handler that compares the new input value with the old, checking for a `\t`. If one is found, advance the field as shown by @boredgames

Assuming the variable `username` contains the value for the username and `setUsername` dispatches an action to change it in the store (component state, redux store, etc), do something like this:

```
function tabGuard (newValue, oldValue, callback, nextCallback) {
  if (newValue.indexOf('\t') >= 0 && oldValue.indexOf('\t') === -1) {
    callback(oldValue)
    nextCallback()
  } else {
    callback(newValue)
  }
}

class LoginScene {
  focusNextField = (nextField) => {
    this.refs[nextField].focus()
  }

  focusOnPassword = () => {
    this.focusNextField('password')
  }

  handleUsernameChange = (newValue) => {
    const { username } = this.props            // or from wherever
    const { setUsername } = this.props.actions // or from wherever

    tabGuard(newValue, username, setUsername, this.focusOnPassword)
  }

  render () {
    const { username } = this.props

    return (
      <TextInput ref='username'
                 placeholder='Username'
                 autoCapitalize='none'
                 autoCorrect={false}
                 autoFocus
                 keyboardType='email-address'
                 onChangeText={handleUsernameChange}
                 blurOnSubmit={false}
                 onSubmitEditing={focusOnPassword}
                 value={username} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me using a physical keyboard. the onChangeText event doesn't fire on tab.

Answer (score 1):

Really annoying that RN doesn't have some sort of Tabindex system.

A functional component, for my use case, I have an array of string IDs for inputs which I iterate through and show one text input each. The following code will automatically jump the user through all of them, stopping the keyboard from disappearing/reappearing between fields and dismissing it at the end, also showing the appropriate "action" button on the keyboard.

Typescript, Native Base.

```js
const stringFieldIDs = [
  'q1', 'q2', 'q3'
];

export default () => {
  const stringFieldRefs = stringFieldIDs.map(() => useRef < any > ());

  const basicStringField = (id: string, ind: number) => {
    const posInd = stringFieldIDs.indexOf(id);
    const isLast = posInd === stringFieldIDs.length - 1;

    return ( <
      Input blurOnSubmit = {
        isLast
      }
      ref = {
        stringFieldRefs[posInd]
      }
      returnKeyType = {
        isLast ? 'done' : 'next'
      }
      onSubmitEditing = {
        isLast ?
        undefined :
          () => stringFieldRefs[posInd + 1].current._root.focus()
      }
      />
    );
  };

  return stringFieldIDs.map(basicStringField);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, } from 'react';

const OTP = (props) => {



    const OTP = [];
    const ref_input = [];
    ref_input[0] = useRef();
    ref_input[1] = useRef();
    ref_input[2] = useRef();
    ref_input[3] = useRef();

    const focusNext = (text, index) => {
        if (index < ref_input.length - 1 && text) {
            ref_input[index + 1].current.focus();
        }
        if (index == ref_input.length - 1) {
            ref_input[index].current.blur();
        }
        OTP[index] = text;
    }
    const focusPrev = (key, index) => {
        if (key === "Backspace" && index !== 0) {
            ref_input[index - 1].current.focus();
        }
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View>
                
                    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        <View style={loginScreenStyle.titleWrap}>
                            <Title style={loginScreenStyle.titleHeading}>Verify OTP</Title>
                            <Subheading style={loginScreenStyle.subTitle}>Enter the 4 digit code sent to your mobile number</Subheading>
                        </View>
                        <View style={loginScreenStyle.inputContainer}>
                            <TextInput
                                mode="flat"
                                selectionColor={Colors.primaryColor}
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                textAlign='center'
                                maxLength={1}
                                keyboardType='numeric'
                                style={formScreenStyle.otpInputStyle}
                                autoFocus={true}
                                returnKeyType="next"
                                ref={ref_input[0]}
                                onChangeText={text => focusNext(text, 0)}
                                onKeyPress={e => focusPrev(e.nativeEvent.key, 0)}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                mode="flat"
                                selectionColor={Colors.primaryColor}
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                textAlign='center'
                                maxLength={1}
                                keyboardType='numeric'
                                style={formScreenStyle.otpInputStyle}
                                ref={ref_input[1]}
                                onChangeText={text => focusNext(text, 1)}
                                onKeyPress={e => focusPrev(e.nativeEvent.key, 1)}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                mode="flat"
                                selectionColor={Colors.primaryColor}
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                textAlign='center'
                                maxLength={1}
                                keyboardType='numeric'
                                style={formScreenStyle.otpInputStyle}
                                ref={ref_input[2]}
                                onChangeText={text => focusNext(text, 2)}
                                onKeyPress={e => focusPrev(e.nativeEvent.key, 2)}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                mode="flat"
                                selectionColor={Colors.primaryColor}
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                textAlign='center'
                                maxLength={1}
                                keyboardType='numeric'
                                style={formScreenStyle.otpInputStyle}
                                ref={ref_input[3]}
                                onChangeText={text => focusNext(text, 3)}
                                onKeyPress={e => focusPrev(e.nativeEvent.key, 3)}
                            />

                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView >
    )
}

export default OTP;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NativeBase as UI Components you can use this sample

```
<Item floatingLabel>
    <Label>Title</Label>
    <Input
        returnKeyType = {"next"}
        autoFocus = {true}
        onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
            this._inputDesc._root.focus(); 
        }} />
</Item>
<Item floatingLabel>
    <Label>Description</Label>
    <Input
        getRef={(c) => this._inputDesc = c}
        multiline={true} style={{height: 100}} />
        onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this._inputLink._root.focus(); }} />
</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onSubmitEditing` is called when `returnKeyType` key is pressed. when you switch to next input, to prevent the flashing (in a fast system can be ignored) `blurOnSubmit={false}`

```
import React, { ReactElement, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {  ScrollView, TextInput as NativeTextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

    
export default function LoginScreen({ navigation, route }: LoginProps): ReactElement {
    const passwordRef = useRef<NativeTextInput | null>(null);
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        username: "player1",
        password: "player1234"
    });
    const setFormInput = (key: keyof typeof form, value: string) =>
        setForm({ ...form, [key]: value });

    return (
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    value={form.username}
                    onChangeText={value => setFormInput("username", value)}
                    returnKeyType="next"
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    placeholder="Username"
                    onSubmitEditing={() => {
                        passwordRef.current?.focus();
                    }}
                />
                <TextInput
                    value={form.password}
                    onChangeText={value => setFormInput("password", value)}
                    ref={passwordRef}
                    returnKeyType="done"
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
            </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here a reagent solution for a input component that has a :focus property.

The field will be focused as long as this prop is set to true and will not have focus as long as this is false.

Unfortunately this component needs to have a :ref defined, I could not find an other way to call .focus() on it. I am happy about suggestions.

```
(defn focusable-input [init-attrs]
  (r/create-class
    {:display-name "focusable-input"
     :component-will-receive-props
       (fn [this new-argv]
         (let [ref-c (aget this "refs" (:ref init-attrs))
               focus (:focus (ru/extract-props new-argv))
               is-focused (.isFocused ref-c)]
           (if focus
             (when-not is-focused (.focus ref-c))
             (when is-focused (.blur ref-c)))))
     :reagent-render
       (fn [attrs]
         (let [init-focus (:focus init-attrs)
               auto-focus (or (:auto-focus attrs) init-focus)
               attrs (assoc attrs :auto-focus auto-focus)]
           [input attrs]))}))
```

https://gist.github.com/Knotschi/6f97efe89681ac149113ddec4c396cc5

Comment: @Bap - this is Clojurescript.  Reagent is a binding to React.  If you're curious, it's a great match for React if you are up for a lisp as stateful updates are generally only possible with things like an explicit call to `swap!` on an `atom` type.  As per the docs, this is used for binding to React: "Any component that uses an atom is automagically re-rendered when its value changes." http://reagent-project.github.io/

Answer (score -1):

If you've wrapped a React Native TextInput within a new component and you find that the ref is not working as expected to move to the next input when submitted, there are a few potential reasons and solutions you can explore:

1. Passing the ref properly:

Ensure that you are correctly passing the ref from the parent component to the wrapped TextInput component. If you are using functional components, you can use the useImperativeHandle hook to expose specific methods or properties of the child component.

2. Using forwardRef:

Ensure that you are using the forwardRef function when creating your custom component. This is necessary to forward the ref from the parent component to the child component.

3. Handling focus in the parent component:

If the ref is properly passed, ensure that you are using the focus() method on the next TextInput component in the parent component's handleSubmit function.

```
//ParentComponent.js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import CustomInput from './CustomInput';

const ParentComponent = () => {
   const inputRef1 = useRef(null);
   const inputRef2 = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // Do something with the input value
    inputRef2.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <CustomInput ref={inputRef1} onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  );
};

// CustomInput.js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

const CustomInput = forwardRef(({ onSubmit }, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TextInput ref={ref} /* other props */ />
      <Button title="Submit" onPress={onSubmit} />
    </>
  );
});

export default CustomInput;
```

worked for me after trying several solutions

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541)

Comment: @starball sorry I didn't know that but this worked with me and I wanted to help