# Why ref='string' is "legacy"?

Tags: reactjs

In the React documentation they say:

> React also supports using a string (instead of a callback) as a ref prop on any component, although **this approach is mostly legacy** at this point.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Take the following example:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    return <input onClick={() => this.action()} ref={input => (this._input = input)} />;
  }
  action() {
    console.log(this._input.value);
  }
}
```

Why should I prefer this, instead of:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    return <input onClick={() => this.action()} ref='input' />;
  }
  action() {
    console.log(this.refs.input.value);
  }
}
```

?

It seems just much more clean and easier the second example.
Are there risks that the string method will be deprecated?

***NB**: I'm looking for the "official" answer to the statement in the documentation, I'm not asking about personal preferences and so on.*

Comment: Is it something to do with this perhaps? https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/24/streamlining-react-elements.html#pending-change-the-refs-semantics
i.e. breaking ref ownership away from parent?  There are other benefits, but I think this was their initial reasoning perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, more reading here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3228#issuecomment-75461381

Answer (score 50, accepted):

While perhaps more simple, the old refs API can get difficult in some edge cases, like when used in a callback. All kind of static analysis is a pain with strings, too. The callback based API can do everything the string API can do *and more* with just a little added verbosity.

```
class Repeat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ul> {
      [...Array(+this.props.times)].map((_, i) => {
        return <li key={i}> { this.props.template(i)    } </li>
      })
    } </ul>
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.refDict = {};
  }

  render() {
    return <Repeat times="3" template={i => <span ref= {el => this.refDict[i] = el}> Hello {i} </span>} />
           {/*                                    ^^^ Try doing this with the string API          */}
  }
}
```

Further discussion and a bit more comprehensive list of the possible issues with the string based api can be found from [issue #1373](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1373), where the callback based api was introduced. I'll include here a list from the issue description:

> The ref API is broken is several aspects.
>
> - You have to refer to this.refs['myname'] as strings to be Closure Compiler Advanced Mode compatible.
> - It doesn't allow the notion of multiple owners of a single instance.
> - Magical dynamic strings potentially break optimizations in VMs.
> - It needs to be always consistent, because it's synchronously resolved. This means that asynchronous batching of rendering introduces potential bugs.
> - We currently have a hook to get sibling refs so that you can have one component refer to it's sibling as a context reference. This only works one level. This breaks the ability to wrap one of those in an encapsulation.
> - It can't be statically typed. You have to cast it at any use in languages like TypeScript.
> - There's no way to attach the ref to the correct "owner" in a callback invoked by a child. `<Child renderer={index => <div ref="test">{index}</div>} />` -- this ref will be attached where the callback is issued, not in the current owner.

---

The docs call the old string API *"legacy"* to make it clearer that the callback-based API is the preferred approach, as is discussed in [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/5ee8a93280987bf1547687f5d8665be89058f321#all_commit_comments) and in [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6692) which are the ones that actually put those statements to the documentation in the first place. Also note that a few of the comments imply that the string based refs api might be *deprecated* at some point.

Comment: I wonder if you could add a note that inlining the callback is a performance hit that is not recommended?  Or so I read here https://hackernoon.com/refs-in-react-all-you-need-to-know-fb9c9e2aeb81

Comment: @GreenAsJade The example has lots of things that I wouldn't do on production code, but since the point is just to demonstrate a pattern that would be difficult to do with the string API, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Besides, I'm doubtful those few extra milliseconds would be anyone's performance bottleneck unless they have thousands of these components.

Answer (score 18):

Originally posted by danabramov on https://news.ycombinator.com/edit?id=12093234

> 1. String refs are not composable. A wrapping component can’t “snoop” on a ref to a child if it already has an existing string ref. On the other hand, callback refs don’t have a single owner, so you can always compose them.
> 2. String refs don’t work with static analysis like Flow. Flow can’t guess the magic that framework does to make the string ref “appear” on `this.refs`, as well as its type (which could be different). Callback refs are friendlier to static analysis.
> 3. The owner for a string ref is determined by the currently executing component. This means that with a common “render callback” pattern (e.g. `<DataTable renderRow={this.renderRow} />`), the wrong component will own the ref (it will end up on `DataTable` instead of your component defining `renderRow`).
> 4. String refs force React to keep track of currently executing component. This is problematic because it makes `react` module stateful, and thus causes weird errors when `react` module is duplicated in the bundle.