# Difference between React Ref property by string and function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React web development, and I'm studying about Component ref. I found this note:

> You can allocate a function as a **ref** property of JSX. This function
>   runs only once when the element is mounted. In this function, you can
>   put a DOM node into instance's property.
>
> ```
> <input ref={(input) => {this.emailInput = input}}
>   className="form-control"
>   type="text"
>   placeholder="cad.co" />
> ```
>
> In current official document, it is recommended to use function for
>   **ref**, and it is mentioned that string ref will likely be deprecated in future
>   version(https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).

I roughly understand that *refs* and *ref* are used as reference variable, and also that for ref property *string literal* can be used.

But I don't get the point about *how to use ref property with function argument*. How can it be the same or similar to the work of using string property for ref?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468913/why-ref-string-is-legacy