# What do I do when a TypeScript definition file I am using is missing a single definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using the [React](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react) type definitions for my project. I notice it is missing the focus method on elements in the [array returned by the refs property](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts#L177) - so I cannot get [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753780/76644) to work. Basically, the compiler says: `property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Component <any, any> | Element'`. This is because *focus* exists on type *HTMLElement* not *Element*. Either the definition file should specify the return type of *refs* as `| HTMLElement` or some other extended interface that includes focus method (I'm not sure which but that's not the point of my question).

My question is: what should I do now? I am stuck from continuing development!

I know I could fork the definition file and patch it myself but this seems to be a problem I keep coming up with in TypeScript and was wondering if there was a less cumbersome solution that means I can move quickly. It seems that I keep having to step out of my tracks in building my app to often do TypeScript patching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is to cast to `any` to **opt out** of type checking i.e.

```
 onSubmitEditing={(event) => { 
    (this.refs.SecondInput as any).focus(); 
 }}
```

Submitting a pull request on DefinitelyTyped would be a nice move....

note: you can become more 'sophisticated' if need be, using "double casting to `any`"

```
 type ProperRef = Component <any, any> | HTMLElement

 onSubmitEditing={(event) => { 
    const secondRef =  this.refs.SecondInput as any as ProperRef;
    secondRef.focus(); 
 }}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the double casting?

Comment: @cubabit. In that particular case none. More generally, when casting to `any`, you opt out of type checking for this variable. With double casting you opt out then back in and benefit from typing again for that variable.