# How do I expose a function of an internal component through a wrapping class in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, shoutem

I am using @shoutem/ui library that has it's own TextInput implementation for react native.

https://github.com/shoutem/ui/blob/develop/components/TextInput.js

I'm trying to set focus on the next input on a keyboard next button press like so

[React Native: How to select the next TextInput after pressing the "next" keyboard button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar)

However, Shoutem/ui's implementation doesn't expose a focus() method for the TextInput that I can use from a reference.

How do I expose the TextInput's focus method as a property in the outer class?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput as RNTextInput } from 'react-native';

import { connectStyle } from '@shoutem/theme';
import { connectAnimation } from '@shoutem/animation';

class TextInput extends Component {
  focus() {
     // how do I expose the react native text input focus method from this class?  
     // do I get a reference to the text input component somehow?
  }
  render() {
    const { props } = this;
    const style = {
      ...props.style,
    };
    delete style.placeholderTextColor;
    delete style.selectionColor;

    return (
      <RNTextInput
        {...props}
        style={style}
        placeholderTextColor={props.style.placeholderTextColor}
        selectionColor={props.style.selectionColor}
      />
    );
  }
}

TextInput.propTypes = {
  ...RNTextInput.propTypes,
  style: React.PropTypes.object,
};

const AnimatedTextInput = connectAnimation(TextInput);
const StyledTextInput = connectStyle('shoutem.ui.TextInput')(AnimatedTextInput);

export {
  StyledTextInput as TextInput,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

```
focus() {
    this.rnInput.focus();
}
render() {
    const { props } = this;
    const style = {
    ...props.style,
    };
    delete style.placeholderTextColor;
    delete style.selectionColor;

    return (
    <RNTextInput
        {...props}
        ref={input => this.rnInput = input}
        style={style}
        placeholderTextColor={props.style.placeholderTextColor}
        selectionColor={props.style.selectionColor}
    />
    );
}
```

A little explanation. The ref callback is executed after the component finishes rendering, you then have a reference for the current instance of this component that you can save in a variable for latter use `ref={input => this.rnInput = input}`. Now you can use `this.rnInput` to call the `focus` method.

Comment: yup that'll do it