# How to autofocus next TextInput on react-native

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, textinput

I'm trying to create a passcode protected screen. The screen will uses 4 numeric input as the passcode.

The way I'm doing this is create a TextInput Component and call it 4 times in my main screen.

The problem I'm having is the TextInputs will not focus on the next one as I type the value of the previous TextInput.

I'm using refs for all PasscodeTextInput component (I've been informed that it is a legacy method but I do not know any other way, alas).

***Tried this method(without creating my own component), no luck too.***
[METHOD](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/42cbc55f5f2c64fa2ed0cacaf3c8f8991fad6137/Examples/UIExplorer/TextInputExample.ios.js#L237)

[image]

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { PasscodeTextInput } from './common';

export default class ProgressBar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { centerEverything, container, passcodeContainer,  textInputStyle} = styles;
    return (
      <View style={[centerEverything, container]}>
        <View style={[passcodeContainer]}>
          <PasscodeTextInput
            autoFocus={true}
            ref="passcode1"
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this.refs.passcode2.focus() }} />
          <PasscodeTextInput
            ref="passcode2"
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this.refs.passcode3.focus() }} />
          <PasscodeTextInput
            ref="passcode3"
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this.refs.passcode4.focus() }}/>
          <PasscodeTextInput
            ref="passcode4" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  centerEverything: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E7DDD3',
  },
  passcodeContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ProgressBar', () => ProgressBar);
```

**PasscodeTextInput.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

const deviceWidth = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
const deviceHeight = require('Dimensions').get('window').height;

const PasscodeTextInput = ({ ref, autoFocus, onSubmitEditing, onChangeText, value}) => {

  const { inputStyle, underlineStyle } = styles;

  return(
    <View>
      <TextInput
        ref={ref}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
        style={[inputStyle]}
        maxLength={1}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        placeholderTextColor="#212121"
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={value}
      />
      <View style={underlineStyle} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = {
  inputStyle: {
    height: 80,
    width: 60,
    fontSize: 50,
    color: '#212121',
    fontSize: 40,
    padding: 18,
    margin: 10,
    marginBottom: 0
  },
  underlineStyle: {
    width: 60,
    height: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#202020',
    marginLeft: 10
  }
}

export { PasscodeTextInput };
```

**Update 1**

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { PasscodeTextInput } from './common';

export default class ProgressBar extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      autoFocus1: true,
      autoFocus2: false,
      autoFocus3: false,
      autoFocus4: false,
    }
  }

  onTextChanged(t) { //callback for immediate state change
    if (t == 2) { this.setState({ autoFocus1: false, autoFocus2: true }, () => { console.log(this.state) }) }
    if (t == 3) { this.setState({ autoFocus2: false, autoFocus3: true }, () => { console.log(this.state) }) }
    if (t == 4) { this.setState({ autoFocus3: false, autoFocus4: true }, () => { console.log(this.state) }) }
  }

  render() {
    const { centerEverything, container, passcodeContainer, testShit, textInputStyle } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={[centerEverything, container]}>
        <View style={[passcodeContainer]}>
          <PasscodeTextInput
            autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus1}
            onChangeText={() => this.onTextChanged(2)} />
          <PasscodeTextInput
            autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus2}
            onChangeText={() => this.onTextChanged(3)} />
          <PasscodeTextInput
            autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus3}
            onChangeText={() => this.onTextChanged(4)} />
          <PasscodeTextInput
            autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus4} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  centerEverything: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E7DDD3',
  },
  passcodeContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ProgressBar', () => ProgressBar);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar Here is the info. Hope this helps.

Comment: @UjjwalNepal The focus() method has deprecated..., and the answer from mitch is not usable after 0.40 http://stackoverflow.com/a/41201939/5809351

Comment: I suppose you can avoid having state in the parent at all, just do a focus of a 1st input in `componentDidMount` and your  `onTextChanged` method can look something like this  `if  t  == 1 or 2 or 3  then focus the t+1'th input`

Comment: @Igorsvee how to do a focus on componentDidMount? Managing state in componentDidMount is discouraging, mind to share some code?

Comment: Sure, since the `componentDidMount` is invoked after the `render` method, it means that the elements have already been rendered and we can now access them via `refs`: ```this.refs.passcode1.focus()```

Comment: add this   autoFocus={true}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot forward the `ref` to `<TextInput>` using that way because `ref` is one of the [special props](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/special-props.html). Thus, calling `this.refs.passcode2` will return you `<PasscodeTextInput>` instead.

Try change to the following to get the `ref` from `<TextInput>`.

**PasscodeTextInput.js**

```
const PasscodeTextInput = ({ inputRef, ... }) => {

  ...

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        ref={(r) => { inputRef && inputRef(r) }}
        ...
      />
    </View>
    ...
  );
}
```

Then, assign the `inputRef` from `<PasscodeTextInput>` to a variable and use `focus()` to switch focus (it is not deprecated as of RN `0.41.2`).

**index.ios.js**

```
return (
  <PasscodeTextInput
    autoFocus={true}
    onChangeText={(event) => { event && this.passcode2.focus() }} />

  <PasscodeTextInput
    inputRef={(r) => { this.passcode2 = r }}
    onChangeText={(event) => { event && this.passcode3.focus() }} />

  <PasscodeTextInput
    inputRef={(r) => { this.passcode3 = r }}
    onChangeText={(event) => { event && this.passcode4.focus() }} />

  <PasscodeTextInput
    inputRef={(r) => { this.passcode4 = r }} />
);
```

P.S: `event && this.passcode2.focus()` prevents focus is switched when trying to clear the old passcode and enter a new one.

Comment: @J.doe : Thanks for the code. Did you remove on delete key press?

Comment: This saves my life and it's simpler than those techniques such as forwardRef. But I still hope that React Native could handle the focus movement natively in the future.

Answer (score 22):

There is a defaultProp for TextInput where one can focus after component mounted.

> ***autoFocus***

If true, focuses the input on componentDidMount, the default value is false. for more information please read the related [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autofocus).

## UPDATE

After `componentDidUpdate` it won't work properly. In that case, one can use `ref` to focus programmatically.

Comment: Your answer is right, but after `componentDidUpdate` it is not working properly.

Comment: In that case one can use ref to focus programmatically. just stating an option.

Answer (score 7):

we handled this style of screen with a different approach.

Rather than manage 4 individual TextInputs and handle the navigation of focus across each one (and then back again when the user deletes a character), we have a single TextInput on screen but is invisible (ie. 0px x 0px) wide which has the focus, maxLength and keyboard configuration, etc.

This TextInput takes input from the user but can't actually been seen, as each character is typed in we render the entered text as a series simple View/Text elements, styled much similar to your screen above.

This approach worked well for us with no need to manage what the 'next' or 'previous' TextInput to focus next to.

Comment: Sweet solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use focus method `onChangeText` as Jason stated, in addition to that adding `maxLength={1}` can make you jump to the next input immediately without checking what's added. (just noticed its **deprecated**, but still this is how I solved my problem, and should do fine until v0.36, and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40837333/4306508) explains how you should update the deprecated function).

```
  <TextInput
   ref="first"
   style={styles.inputMini}
   maxLength={1}
   keyboardType="numeric"
   returnKeyType='next'
   blurOnSubmit={false}
   placeholderTextColor="gray"
   onChangeText={(val) => {
      this.refs['second'].focus()
   }}
  />
  <TextInput
   ref="second"
   style={styles.inputMini}
   maxLength={1}
   keyboardType="numeric"
   returnKeyType='next'
   blurOnSubmit={false}
   placeholderTextColor="gray"
   onChangeText={(val) => {
     this.refs['third'].focus()
   }}
  />
  ...
```

Please notice that my use of refs are deprecated too, but I've just copied the code since I can guarantee you that was working back then (hopefully works now too).

Finally, **the main issue with this type of implementation is**, once you try to remove a number with backspace your focus will jump to next one, causing serious UX issues. However, you can listen for backspace key entry and perform something different instead of focusing to next input. So I'll leave a [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1882) here for you to further investigate if you choose to use this type of implementation.

**Hacky Solution to Previously Described Issue:** If you check what's entered in `onChangeText` prop before doing anything, you can jump to next input if the value is a **number**, else (that's a backspace), jump back. (Just came up with this idea, I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that `onSubmitEditing` is when you hit the "return" or "enter" key on the regular keyboard... there is not one of those buttons on the keypad.

Assuming you want each input to only have one character, you could look at the `onChangeText` and then check if text has length 1 and call focus if the length is indeed 1.

Comment: I thought so, I made some changes to my code my it still wont work

Answer (score 1):

```
    <TextInput 
    ref={input => {
          this.nameOrId = input;
        }}
    />



    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={()=>{
        this.nameOrId.focus()
      }}
     >
      <Text>Click</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve with this code:
const VerifyCode: React.FC = ({ pass, onFinish }) => {

```
      const inputsRef = useRef<Input[] | null[]>([]);
      const [active, setActive] = useState<number>(0);

      const onKeyPress = ({ nativeEvent }: 
      NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputKeyPressEventData>) => {
       if (nativeEvent.key === "Backspace") {
        if (active !== 0) {
          inputsRef.current[active - 1]?.focus();
          return setActive(active - 1);
        }
       } else {
          inputsRef.current[active + 1]?.focus();
          return setActive(active + 1);
       }
      return null;
     };

   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StyledInput
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        autoFocus={active === 0}
        ref={(r) => {
          inputsRef.current[0] = r;
        }}
      />
      <StyledInput
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        autoFocus={active === 1}
        ref={(r) => {
          inputsRef.current[1] = r;
        }}
      />
      <StyledInput
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        autoFocus={active === 2}
        ref={(r) => {
          inputsRef.current[2] = r;
        }}
      />
      <StyledInput
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        autoFocus={active === 3}
        ref={(r) => {
          inputsRef.current[3] = r;
        }}
      />
    </View>
 );
};

export default VerifyCode;
```

I put one ref in all the inputs, and when the onKeyPress fire, the function verify if have to go back or go to next input

Comment: Hi there. try explaining why your solution works. This makes it more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing autoFocus={true} and setting timeout.
I have a popup as a functional component and using "current.focus()" with Refs like this:

```
   const Popup = ({   placeholder,   autoFocus,   showStatus, }) => {  const inputRef = useRef(null);   useEffect(() => {
     Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? inputRef.current.focus()
        : setTimeout(() => inputRef.current.focus(), 40);   }, [showStatus]);   return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputText}
        defaultValue={placeholder}
        ref={inputRef}
      />
    </View>  };
```