# Cannot turn autoCorrect to {false} in react native TextInput

Tags: ios, react-native, text, keyboard

On my TextInput change text, I detect whether the user pushed the `@` button for mentions.

```
onChangeText(text){
    const suggestTrigger = text.match(/\B@[A-Za-z0-9]*$/i) //grab "@" trigger
    const searchQuery = (suggestTrigger && suggestTrigger.length > 0) ? suggestTrigger[0] : null;
    this.setState({
        searchQuery: searchQuery
    })
}
```

Then, in my render, I do:

```
<TextInput 
    autoCapitalize={this.state.searchQuery ? "none" : "sentences"}
    autoCorrect={this.state.searchQuery ? false : true}
    onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
/>
```

However, even when I do this, the autoCorrect does *not* turn off.

I still see this:

[image]

This is causing problems because oftentimes the system replaces the entire mention with a different word altogether.

How can I turn autoCorrect and autoCapitalize *off* when the user pushes the `@` button?
'
I have even tried rendering an entirely different , but the behavior remains.

Comment: This seems to work for me.  https://snack.expo.io/B1PMIxzTm

Comment: @gtfargo it may work on snack but it doesn't work on real device (exact code)

Comment: which version of react-native are you using?

Comment: Would you please upload a sample project?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, Absolutely it is an issue from `iOS` native side and should be fixed from the native side of the project, but I add an innovative solution for solving this problem.

Comment: I think so, I was planing to investigate and try to fix it from native side and tell you the solution. So you found a solution for it?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, Thanks a lot, I found a way and post it as answer it this current post.

Comment: @TIMEX, One another thing that is not related to your question. please do not use `regex` in `react native` projects. if your regex has a bug and user insert a damn pattern it causes to CPU spike and CRASH, and you can not find it out why the app crashed, read [this link](https://medium.com/@liran.tal/node-js-pitfalls-how-a-regex-can-bring-your-system-down-cbf1dc6c4e02). Also, don't use ternary, unless there is not any other way. for your case you could write `autoCorrect={!this.state.searchQuery}`.

Comment: Do you find any way to disable auto-correction for iOS devices on its keyboard?

Answer (score 13):

***TL;DR***: you should close and re-launch your keyboard after the `TextInput` `autoCorrect` toggling value.

Buddy, this is not your fault, I had the same issue on `autoFocus` of `react native` `TextInput` component. I set a `state` name for the `TextInput` `editable` prop and then with the pressing `pencil` button I change the `editable` props. The designer told me after the `TextInput` made editable the cursor should be focused, so I use the `isEditable` state for `autoFocus` prop, see below:

```
state = {
  isEditable: false
};

handleEdit = () => {
  const { isEditable } = this.state;
  this.setState({ isEditable: !isEditable });
};

<TextInput
  autoFocus={isEditable}
  editable={isEditable}
  style={styles.textNameEditable}
  defaultValue={text}
  numberOfLines={1}
/>
```

[image]

Then I press the edit button and it turns to:

[image]

But it is not focused and the Keyboard didn't launch, I sought and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50922197/6877799), the `TextInput` does not change/update some of its props after `componentDidMount`. ☹️. Also, it is not different in `iOS` or `Android`, both of them has this issue, I used `ref` to focus on this `TextInput` after the `isEditable` state made `true`. see following code:

```
<TextInput
  editable={isEditable}
  style={styles.textNameEditable}
  defaultValue={text}
  numberOfLines={1}
  ref={input => {
    this.input = input;
  }}
/>

componentDidUpdate() {
  const { isEditable } = this.state;
  if (isEditable) {
    this.input.focus();
  }
}
```

### And your case:

Absolutely you can not use `ref` because the `autoCorrect` should render with `react native` and it is not like `focus()` and `blur()` so `JavaScript` cannot access to it.

I make a test shape for your case, I create another button like a star for toggling `autoCorrect` value alongside my edit button. the filled star means `autoCorrect` is `true` and the lined star means `autoCorrect` is `false`, now see the test area code and view:

```
state = {
  isEditable: false,
  correct: true
};

handleCorrect = () => {
  const { correct } = this.state;
  this.setState({ correct: !correct });
};

<TextInput
  autoCorrect={correct}
  editable={isEditable}
  style={styles.textNameEditable}
  defaultValue={text}
  numberOfLines={1}
  ref={input => {
    this.input = input;
  }}
/>
```

[image]

In the above photo, it is so clear the `autoCorrect` rendered as `true`, so it is enabled:

[image]

When I write a wrong Persian word the auto-correction show its suggestion, now time to press the star button:

[image]

Wow, the `autoCorrection` is `false` in the above situation but still we see the auto-correction of the cellphone. it is just like `autoFocus` it is rendered in the first render and after it, the `TextInput` could not change/update its props. suddenly I press edit button:

[image]

And I press the edit button again, so surely, you realized the `autoCorrect` is `false` now, ok now see what I saw:

[image]

The `autoCorrect` remained `false` by my double pressing edit button and now the auto-correction of device disappears completely. I don't know it is a bug or my bad understanding but I realized in this test area, for update **`autoCorrect`** value, we should do something after changing its value to close the iPhone keyboard and then re-launch it. the main thing that `TextInput` has issued is the launched keyboard.

For my test, when I pressed the edit button the `editable` prop of the `TextInput` is changed to false and the keyboard is closed, so when I pressed the edit button again, the `TextInput` get focused and keyboard re-launched with new `autoCorrect` value. ***This is The Secret***.

### Solution:

You should do something, to close and open again the iOS keyboard with the new `autoCorrect` value. for the test case that I wrote for your question, I decided to do a hybrid innovative solution, using `ref` and the callback of `setState`:

```
handleCorrect = () => {
  const { correct } = this.state;
  this.input.blur(); //-- this line close the keyboard
  this.setState({ correct: !correct },
    () => {
      setTimeout(() => this.input.focus(), 50);
      //-- above line re-launch keyboard after 50 milliseconds
      //-- this 50 milliseconds is for waiting to closing keyborad finish
    }
  );
};


<TextInput
  autoCorrect={correct}
  editable={isEditable}
  style={styles.textNameEditable}
  defaultValue={text}
  numberOfLines={1}
  ref={input => {
    this.input = input;
  }}
/>
```

[image]

And after pressing the star button the keyboard close and re-launch and the auto-correction disappear completely.

[image]

**Note**: *obviously, I summarized some other codes like destructuring and writing class or extends and etc for better human readability*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't in your code completely(except Regex part which didn't work in my device) but how the `React Native` renders Keyboard.
I created a sample that along with your initial code also changes `backgroundColor` of the screen.
You will find that color changes instantly when '@' is entered whereas the keyboard doesn't.
Unless you reload the keyboard. For this, if you un-comment the code it dismisses keyboard once and once you tap back on `textInput` the new Keyboard without autoCorrect and `autoCapitalize` is shown.

```
    state = {
    searchQuery: null,
    isFocused: true,
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);
}

onChangeText = (val) => {
  const suggestTrigger = val.match(/@[A-Za-z0-9]*$/i) //grab "@" trigger
  const searchQuery = (suggestTrigger && suggestTrigger.length > 0) ? suggestTrigger[0] : null;
  // Un comment this to reload
  // if(searchQuery && this.state.isFocused) {
  //   this.setState({
  //     isFocused: false
  // });
  // Keyboard.dismiss();
  //   // this.myTextInput.focus()
  // }
  this.setState({
      searchQuery: searchQuery
  })
}
  render() {
    const { searchQuery } = this.state
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container,
        {
        backgroundColor: searchQuery ? "red": "green"}
      ]}>
        <TextInput 
        style={{width: 300, height: 50, borderWidth: 1}}
        ref={(ref)=>{this.myTextInput = ref}}
          autoCapitalize={searchQuery ? "none" : "sentences"}
          autoCorrect={searchQuery ? false : true}
          onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Since now we know the main cause of error may be a better solution can be reached.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions:
First, have you tried using the autoCorrect fallback?

```
spellCheck={this.state.searchQuery ? false : true}
```

Second, have you tried with native code (Obj-C / Swift)?

```
import { Platform, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { iOSAutoCorrect } from './your-native-code';

const shouldWork = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? <iOSAutoCorrect /> : <TextInput 
autoCapitalize={this.state.searchQuery ? "none" : "sentences"}
autoCorrect={this.state.searchQuery ? false : true}
onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />

return (<View>{shouldWork}</View>);
```

In iOSAutoCorrect you should use a UITextView. Then set its proper value depending on your condition:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // or UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes
```

I have free-coded, thus the code is untested and might contain bugs.