# How to clear TexInput when onChangeText is called after onSubmitEditing?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a functional component in which I am trying to clear a `TextInput` on submit. Sometimes the `onChangeText` callback is called *after* `onSubmitEditing`, so the input is not clear after submitting. Most often this happens due to autocorrect, but sometimes happens with random strings that were not autocorrected. How do I make sure the input is cleared consistently?

Code: https://snack.expo.io/hy4dKvvnr

```
export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={(value) => {
          console.log('CHANGE TEXT', value);
          setInputValue(value);
        }}
        blurOnSubmit
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          console.log('SUBMIT TEXT');
          setInputValue('');
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Console logs:

```
iPhone 8: CHANGE TEXT Kdjgw
iPhone 8: SUBMIT TEXT
iPhone 8: CHANGE TEXT Kdjgw
```

Comment: This seems like it is specific to autocorrect. I can see that the phone itself replaces the input field with the autocorrected value after I submit.
One way would be to turn off autocorrect. I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212534/cannot-turn-autocorrect-to-false-in-react-native-textinput).

Comment: Another way to avoid this is add a timeout before clearing the value in `onSubmitEditing`. But this causes the autocorrected value to be submitted.



Something like:
`onSubmitEditing={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('SUBMIT TEXT');
            setInputValue('');
          }, 25);
        }}`

Comment: @Anish Thanks! For anyone interested, I found the current issue for this problem here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29073.