# Keyboard isn't shown upon TextInput autoFocus [react native]

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput, autofocus

I have this *reply* button in my app where when a user press it, it will change the `TextInput autoFocus` to **true**. I set the autoFocus value to **false** as default value and keep it in a state. I see the state will change to **true** but it doesn't open the keyboard.

This is my TextInput :

```
<TextInput
    autoFocus={this.state.textInputFocus}
    selectTextOnFocus={true}
    ref={ref => this.textInputRef = ref}
    multiline = {true}
    placeholder="Write a comment ..."
    onChangeText={(postComment) => this.setState({postComment})}
    value={this.state.postComment} />
```

Here is the function to change the state when reply button is pressed :

```
_openReplyBox(comment_id, commenter){
    this.setState({ postComment: commenter, textInputFocus: true })
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371023/how-to-autofocus-next-textinput-on-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordinig to docs:

[autoFocus](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#autofocus): If true, focuses the input on componentDidMount. The default value is false

You can use refs to achieve the same functionality.

```
 <TextInput
        ref={"textRef"}
        ...
      />
```

In openReplyBox:

```
_openReplyBox(comment_id, commenter){
    this.refs.textRef.focus();
    this.setState({ postComment: commenter})
}
```