# React Native + Redux Form - Use keyboard next button to go to next TextInput field

Tags: react-native, redux-form

I'm using [Redux Form](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/) (RF) in a React Native application. Everything works fine but I can not figure out how to get the `refs` from the **Field** input to go to the next input field with Redux Form.

Without RF [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar) solution would work just fine.

Here is my code:

```
class RenderInput extends Component {
   const { input, nextField, refs,
        meta: { touched, error, warning },
        input: { onChange } } = this.props
   render() {
      return (
         <Input
            returnKeyType = {'next'}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            onBlur={input.onBlur}
            onFocus={input.onFocus}
            onSubmitEditing = {(event) => {
               // refs is undefined
               refs[nextField].focus()
            }}/>
      )
   }
}

class Form extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <Field
            name="field1"
            focus
            withRef
            ref='field1'
            nextField = "field2"
            component={RenderInput}/>

         <Field
            name="vendor"
            withRef
            ref="field2"
            nextAction = "field3"
            component={RenderInput}/>
      )
   }
}
```

I'm passing on the property `nextField` to the component to determine the next input field when the `Next` key on the keyboard is clicked but I can not get the `refs` property inside the `RenderInput` component.

Any idea how to get the **refs** property?

Comment: Just saying, assigning a ref directly is deprecated. The best thing to do, is assigning the ref to a global variable that you can reuse after: `ref={(componentRef) => this.myRef = componentRef}`. See [React Documentation](http://reactjs.cn/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Comment: I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401396/6242582 how I solved this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solution passes props from the `Form` component to the `RenderInput` component and passes a function call back.

Here's the code:

```
class RenderInput extends Component {
   const { input, refField, onEnter,
        meta: { touched, error, warning },
        input: { onChange } } = this.props
   render() {
      return (
         <TextInput
            ref = {refField}
            returnKeyType = {'next'}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            onBlur={input.onBlur}
            onFocus={input.onFocus}
            onSubmitEditing={onEnter}/>
      )
   }
}

class Form extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <Field
            name="field1"
            focus
            withRef
            ref={(componentRef) => this.field1 = componentRef}
            refField="field1"
            component={RenderInput}
            onEnter={() => { 
               this.field2.getRenderedComponent().refs.field2.focus()
            }}/>

         <Field
            name="field2"
            withRef
            ref={(componentRef) => this.field2 = componentRef}
            refField="field2"
            component={RenderInput}/>
      )
   }
}
```

So what happened here?

1. I assign the ref to local scope with `ref={(componentRef) => this.field1 = componentRef}` as @Ksyqo suggested. Thanks for the hint.
2. I pass `refField="field1"` to the RenderInput and assign the value to the input ref property `ref = {refField}`. This will add the input object to the refs property.
3. I assigned a `onEnter` function in the Field
4. I pass the function to the props of RenderInput and assign it to the `onSubmitEditing={onEnter}` function. Now we have bind the two functions together. That means if `onSubmitEditing` gets invoked the `onEnter` function gets invoked as well
5. Finally, refer to the local field `field2`, get the rendered Component and use the refs, which we assigned in the `Input` field, to set the focus. **this.field2.getRenderedComponent().refs.field2.focus()**

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution but it works.

Comment: One issue I'm still having is that if I import the RenderInput  class from from another file then I get the error focus is not a function. but If i define it with the same file it works.

Comment: Make sure your `export` and `import` the **RenderInput** component correctly. The solution I posted supposed to be two separate files. It definitely works on my end.

Comment: Also, it is very important to use a React component such as `class RenderInput extends Component{}` as **getRenderedComponent()** doesn't work on a stateless function component.

Comment: Weird. The RenderInput  does render on to screen. its just the foucs() function that fails.

Comment: That is weird. Just `console.log(this.field2.getRenderedComponent().refs)` in the `onEnter` function of the `Field` to see whether you get the correct `componentRef` component. `refs` should be an object with all fields as props and double check the `refField` props of the `Field`

Comment: I figured it out: I was using FormInput component(react-native-elements) instead of TextInput in the external file. and apparently Forminput does not have the focus function

Comment: Well spotted. I forgot to mention that I was using the native-base component **Input**, which is inherited from react-native **TextInput**. I will update the answer accordingly!

Comment: is it possible for you to share the the gist? I also tried Input from native-base it didn't work it only works with TextInput

Comment: Update: the following is what worked for me when using Input from Native-base. ;`field2.getRenderedComponent().refs.field2._root.focus()`

Comment: May be it worked in past but it doesn't not work right now.
`field2.getRenderedComponent().refs` is empty object now

Answer (score 1):

For people who are using Redux Form + React Native Elements, just follow @Thomas Dittmar answer, and add the following prop to the 'FormInput' component: `textInputRef={refField}`

The newest version of React Native Element has added the focus() method, so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I"m facing an issue where doing this breaks the field's validation (it always validates to true). Have you faced that before?

Answer (score 1):

`withRef` is deprecated, use `forwardRef` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on getting a ref like this that worked for me.

```
           const renderComp = ({
             refName,
             meta: { touched, error },
             input,
             ...custom
           }) => (
             <MyComponent
               ref={refName}
               {...custom}
             />
           )

            <Field
              name={name}
              component={renderComp}
              ref={node =>
                isLeft ? (this.compRef1 = node) : (this.compRef2 = node)}
              refName={node =>
                 (this.myRef= node) }
              withRef
            />
```

now access instance functions like this.

```
this.myRef.anyFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different use case, but I imagine it works for the above as well.

I used the focus action

```
import { focus } from 'redux-form';
dispatch(focus('signIn', 'email'));
```

Then in the (custom) form field that contains the TextInput, I added in the render function

```
<TextInput
    ref="email"
/>
formStates.filter((state) => meta[state]).map((state) => {
   if(state === 'active'){
      this.refs.email.focus()
   }
})
```

No worries about the component nesting/hierarchy anymore.