# Focus on next Input field on Enter in Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, focus, redux-form, refs

I want to define a HOC(higher order Component) which will be responsible for handling the functionality.
import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
const NextFieldOnEnter = WrappedContainer =>
  class extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('hoc', this.refs);
      //move to next input field
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedContainer {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
export default NextFieldOnEnter;
```

It says *this.refs is deprecated*. So how can I achieve **tab** like behavior when **enter** key is pressed.
My form is

```
<Form>
<Field
  withRef
  hasFeedback
  name="name"
  ref={ref => {
    this.field1 = ref;
  }}
  refField = "field1"
  component={makeField}
  type="date"
/>  
<Field
    withRef
    hasFeedback
    name="address"
    ref={ref => {
      this.field2 = ref;
    }}
     refField ="field2"
    component={makeField}
    type="date"
  />
</Form>
```

//makefield

```
render() {
  const {type, input, label, ref, refField, ...rest} = this.props;
  return (
    <Form.Item
      label={label}
      colon={false}
      type={type}
      value={value}
      ref={ref}
    >
      <Input {...props} />
    </Form.Item>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you replicate this code in codesandbox for the community to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor method define your ref like this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.field1 = React.createRef();
  this.field2 = React.createRef();
}
```

In your render where you are using `ref` do this.

```
<Field
  withRef
  hasFeedback
  name="name"
  ref={this.field1} // Proper way to assign ref in react ver 16.4
  refField = "field1"
  component={makeField}
  type="date"
/>
```

Reference [Refs Documentation React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: it throws an error:  _react2.default.createRef is not a function

Comment: which version of React are you using?

Comment: "react": "^16.2.0"

Comment: You need to use react ^16.4 (the latest one)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this issue:
**My Form with the field components:**
When **expirationDate** field is active and the user presses the next key, the focus goes to the next field called **securityCode** . Also, when **securityCode** is active, and the user presses the next button, we submitted the form (because this is the last field of the form). This is why this Field has the **onSubmitEditing** prop defined.

```
<Form>
  <Field
    name={'expirationDate'}
    component={renderInputRef}
    withRef
    forwardRef
    ref={componentRef => (this.expirationDate = componentRef)}
    refField="expirationDate"
    onEnter={() => {
        try {
        this.cvc.getRenderedComponent().refs.cvc._root.focus();
        } catch {
        /*Do nothing */
        }
    }}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        try {
            if (newValue?.length == 5) {
                this.cvc.getRenderedComponent().refs.cvc._root.focus();
            }
        } catch {
        /*Do nothing */
        }
    }}
  />

  <Field
    name={'securityCode'}
    component={renderInputRef}
    onSubmitEditing={!invalid ? handleSubmit(this.submit) : null}
    accessibilityLabel={'new-card-cvc'}
    keyboardType={'number-pad'}
    withRef
    forwardRef
    refField="cvc"
    ref={componentRef => (this.cvc = componentRef)}
  />
</Form>
```

And the **renderInputRef** component: (In this project we're using native-base, but it's almost the same without it.)

```
export class renderInputRef extends PureComponent<Props> {
 render() {
  const {
    input,
    onEnter,
    refField,
    display,
    description,
    iconRight,
    meta: { touched, warning },
    ...custom
  } = this.props;
  var hasError = touched && (error !== undefined || warning !== undefined);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Item 
        withRef
        forwardRef
      >
        <Input
          ref={refField}
          returnKeyType={'next'}
          onSubmitEditing={onEnter}
          {...input}
          {...custom}
        />
      </Item>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [callback ref **funtion**](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) to create an array of refs that can be used for cycling between fields. It will work with 16.2 and newer.

Show solution when ready ;)