# How to use useRef hook to select next TextInput after pressing next keyboard button with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-form, textinput, react-hooks

I know we can do this easily with react class method.because we have this.ref.
but I am not sure how to do this with useRef hook in functional component.

using tricks written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917795/react-native-redux-form-use-keyboard-next-button-to-go-to-next-textinput-fie/43952870)

This is how I am trying to do this.

```
  ...

  const inputEl1 = useRef(null);
  const inputEl2 = useRef(null);
  return (
        <Field
            name="first_name"
            component={MyTextInput}
            placeholder="First name"
            ref={inputEl1}
            refField={inputEl1}
            onEnter={() => {
              inputEl2.current.focus();
            }}
          />
          />
          <Field
            name="last_name"
            placeholder="Last name"
            component={MyTextInput}
            ref={inputEl2}
            refField={inputEl2}
          />
)
...
```

So I need to pass ref from field to MyTextInput and on nextKeyPress I want to focus to second input component i.e inputEl2

// My Text Input

```
...
render() {
    const {
      input: { value, onChange, onBlur },
      meta: { touched, error },
      keyboardType,
      placeholder,
      secureTextEntry,
      editable,
      selectTextOnFocus,
      style,
      selectable,
      customValue,
      underlineColorAndroid,
      autoFocus,
      maxLength,
      returnKeyType,
      onEnter,
      refField,
    } = this.props;
    const { passwordVisibility, undelineColor } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ marginVertical: 8 }}>
        <TextInput
          style={[{
            height: 50,
            paddingLeft: 20,
            color: Colors.SECONDARY_COMMON,
          }, style]}
          onBlur={val => onBlur(val)}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          underlineColorAndroid={undelineColor}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          returnKeyType={returnKeyType || 'go'}
          value={customValue || value.toString()}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          onSubmitEditing={onEnter}
          ref={refField}
        />
)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
const inputEl2 = useRef(null);
<TextInput
        name="first_name"           
        placeholder="First name"
        onSubmitEditing={() => inputEl2.current.focus()}
      />

<TextInput
        name="last_name"
        placeholder="Last name"
        ref={inputEl2}
      />
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 6):

If it is a child component you are trying to get the ref of, you need to pass the prop as some other name rather than `ref`.

**This method worked for me**

For hooks, useRef to init ref.

```
const passwordInput = useRef(null);
```

Use a different name for ref prop for custom component, e.g. inputRef.

```
<CustomInput
  inputRef={ passwordInput }
/>
```

Child component - Set ref as custom ref prop.

```
const CustomInput = props => {
  const { inputRef } = props;
  
  return ( <TextInput
    { ...props }
    ref={ inputRef }
  /> );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If a child needs to use a prop like a ref as in `<TextInput ref={refField}...`, then the prop needs to be a ref (not a string):

```
<Field refField={inputEl2} ...
```

Comment: I tried this as well. still no luck :(
when I am pressing next key on mobile keyboard it says. undefined is not an object( evaluating inputEl2.currunt.focus.

Comment: do you have the typo `currunt` -> `current` in your code too? if not, try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve example where you `tried this as well` - the problem is most likely somewhere that you didn't show us yet

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. But still I am getting inputEl2.current.focus is not a function.
Thanks for sharing the above link. will read that too.

I guess redux form's filed component won't recognise the useRef. As their code is not updated to hooks. 
correct me if I am wrong. Is this possible?

I guess as per the react doc, I am using this correctly now
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref