# returnKeyType = "next" issue in react native

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

I am using `returnKeyType = "next"` in TextInput component, but it is working like `returnKeyType="go"` instead of moving to the next textinput field.

How can we move from one textinput field to next textinput field using the "next" button on the keyboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: How to select the next TextInput after pressing the "next" keyboard button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar)

Answer (score 6):

You need to set focus on the next textfield using the reference like this:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <TextInput style={{height:40}} 
        placeholder="First TextField Input"
        placeholderTextColor="#DCDCDC"
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={()=>this.secondTextInput.focus()}/>
    <TextInput style={{height:40}} 
        placeholder="Second TextField Input"
        placeholderTextColor="#DCDCDC"
        returnKeyType="go"
        ref={(input)=>this.secondTextInput = input}/> 
</View>
```

Comment: That's a wrong way to implement as it will hide the keyboard on 'next' press and then on focus it will pop-up again instead of just focusing the next field without closing the keyboard

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: instead of down voting you can propose the answer

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi There is a difference between knowing what is a bad solution and actually knowing the answer

Comment: @hardworker Could you please propose your good answer for this question instead of downvoting, I am not an expert, a learner only.

Comment: Set `blurOnSubmit={false}` on the first TextInputField to avoid keyboard closing