# React Native - how to prevent keyboard show/hide toggle between fields

Tags: react-native

So I have some input fields, and as I fill text in one field, and click on another, the keyboard hides and I have to click on the field again to make the keyboard show again.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you have for your input fields and their `onSubmitEditing` functions?

Comment: I have not used `onSubmitEditing`.. its simple fields

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301596/returnkeytype-next-issue-in-react-native/48307053#48307053

Comment: does your input fields wrapper around `ScrollView` ?

Comment: its a view, inside view, inside view, inside scrollView. so eventually yes

Answer (score 1):

In scroll view you should add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` property. Try with `handled` or 'always' values. Here is [the link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) of react native documentation

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
    //TextInputs ...
</ScrollView>
```