# returnKeyLabel vs returnKeyType react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have tested the both but `returnKeyLabel` does not do anything. I am using the Android Platform.

What is the difference between `returnKeyLabel` and `returnKeyType` in `react native`? What is the exact use case of `returnKeyLabel` in `react native`?

[Documentation reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#returnkeylabel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I was under the impression that `returnKeyLabel` was just an Android-specific version of `returnKeyType`, although the latter does have the Android-specific values `none` and `previous`, which is a little confusing.

It may have something to do with the `next` and `go` value behaviors in `returnKeyType` as referenced here: [returnKeyType = "next" issue in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301596/returnkeytype-next-issue-in-react-native)