# after typing focus to next text input

Tags: javascript, react-native

let say I have 3 views with `TextInput` inside it.

```
<View style={styles.row}>
    <TextInput
        ref={'cell_'+i}
        maxLength={1}
        spellCheck={false}
        style={styles.chewy}
        onKeyPress={this._onInputFilled} />
</View>
<View style={styles.row}>
    <TextInput
        ref={'cell_'+i}
        maxLength={1}
        spellCheck={false}
        style={styles.chewy}
        onKeyPress={this._onInputFilled} />
</View>
<View style={styles.row}>
    <TextInput
        ref={'cell_'+i}
        maxLength={1}
        spellCheck={false}
        style={styles.chewy}
        onKeyPress={this._onInputFilled} />
</View>
```

notice `ref={'cell_'+i}` where `i` equal to 0..2. now when I type in a char inside `cell_0` how to focus (move the cursor) to the next TextInput ie.`cell_1`?

Comment: Now you can typing cell_0 when did you move to cell_1 ?

Comment: This link might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<View style={styles.row}>
    <TextInput
        ref={'cell_'+i}
        maxLength={1}
        spellCheck={false}
        style={styles.chewy}
        onKeyPress={this._onInputFilled}
        onSubmitEditing={() => this.focusNextField('cell_' + (i+1))}
        />
</View>
<View style={styles.row}>
    <TextInput
        ref={'cell_'+i}
        maxLength={1}
        spellCheck={false}
        style={styles.chewy}
        onKeyPress={this._onInputFilled}
        onSubmitEditing={() => this.focusNextField('cell_' + (i+1))}
        />
</View>
<View style={styles.row}>
    <TextInput
        ref={'cell_'+i}
        maxLength={1}
        spellCheck={false}
        style={styles.chewy}
        onKeyPress={this._onInputFilled}
        />
</View>
```

onSubmitEditing:

```
focusNextField = nextField => {
   this.refs[nextField].focus();
};
```