# React Native - Shift focus to next Input box upon pressing "Next" button in keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, input

I am very new in react Native world.
I want to shift focus from the first input box to second input box.
Please find my below code.

```
<View style={styles.inputViewStyle}>
                  <TextInput
                    ref={firstnameRef => (this.firstnameRef = 
                    firstnameRef)}
                    label="Firstname"
                    returnKeyType="next"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    value={this.state.firstname}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => 
              this.refs.middlenameRef.focus()}
                    onChangeText={firstname => this.setState({ firstname })}
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                  />
                </View> 

    <View style={styles.inputViewStyle}>
                  <TextInput
                    ref={middlenameRef => (this.middlenameRef = middlenameRef)}
                    label="Middlename"
                    returnKeyType="go"
                    value={this.state.middlename}
                    onChangeText={middlename => this.setState({ middlename })}
                  />
                </View>
```

I am getting error -> "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this2.middlenameRef.focus()')"

UPDATE: 
`constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstname: "",
      middlename: "",
      lastname: ""

    };`

Please guide. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: How to select the next TextInput after pressing the "next" keyboard button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar)

Comment: Can you provide your constructor code?

Comment: HungrySoul: Please check.

@QuocNguyen - I have tried that solutiion but somehow it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextInput
    placeholder = "FirstTextInput"
    returnKeyType = { "next" }
    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
/>
<TextInput
    ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
    placeholder = "secondTextInput"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the second TextInput focus, when the previous TextInput's onSubmitEditing is triggered.

Try this

1. Adding a Ref to second TextInput
   ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
2. Bind focus function to first TextInput's onSubmitEditing event.
   onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
3. Remember to set blurOnSubmit to false, to prevent keyboard flickering.
   blurOnSubmit={false}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onSubmitEditing={() => { this.middlenameRef.focus() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get instance directly through this. And null Checking could be a good option for debug.

```
onSubmitEditing={() => this.middlenameRef && this.middlenameRef.focus()}
```