# How do I focus on a dynamically created TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I have a Flatlist that is creating a list of my custom component DocumentItem. DocumentItem contains a TextInput:

```
<TextInput style={styles.title} editable={props.isEditable}>{props.title}</TextInput>
```

For each of these TextInputs created, I also have a button called "Rename" that I want to focus on that TextInput and make it editable when it is clicked.

```
<MenuOption onSelect={() => {}} text='Rename' />
```

However, I can't think of a way to reference the dynamically created TextInput

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference of your textinput component and then just call yourReference.focus() method in the button onPress action

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753780/5754159)

Comment: But that's the problem. I don't know how to dynamically create a reference for the TextInputs