# React Native | Forwarding to next input

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am using react native hook. I want to focus on the next textinput when I press Next. I get the error 'focus' is not defined. What is the cause and remedy?

```
const ref_input = useRef();

<TextInput
    ..
    returnKeyType={'next'}
    onSubmitEditing={() => ref_input.current.focus()}/>
<TextInput
    ..
    ref={ref_input}/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: How to select the next TextInput after pressing the "next" keyboard button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar)

Comment: Try to `useRef(null)`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Thanks for comment. Not working.