# React Native auto focus next input on submit

Tags: react-native

I have a form that is generated by the object, and the size is different each time.

I see other examples hard coding to make it jump to the next field. however that is the not gonna work for my case.

so my question is : **How to make on onSubmitEditing jump to the next field when return key is clicked.**

similar question : [React Native: How to select the next TextInput after pressing the "next" keyboard button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748718/react-native-how-to-select-the-next-textinput-after-pressing-the-next-keyboar)

My tries:
creating a list of useref in a list and passing correct index in to TextInput  :

```
 var listOfRef =[]
 myObj.map( (item,index)=> listOfRef[index]=useRef())
```

but this giving me an error  Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.